# Does a seafarer travelling to Dubrovnik from Mumbai via Munich need a Transit visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas, muc

I am a seafarer and my visa will be stamped after reaching Croatia. I have my flight scheduled from Mumbai to Dubrovnik via Munich (in a Schengen country).

Do I need a transit visa for Schengen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traveling through Munich Airport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/traveling-through-munich-airport)

Comment: It looks like you need an airport transit visa. There are several documents that would exempt you from that requirement, but if I understand your question correctly, you don't hold any of those documents.

Comment: @phoog seamen are often exempted when traveling directly to their point of embarkation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: @JonathanReez they can get a visa to enter the Schengen area at the border, without having to get it in advance.  Presumably the same is true in Croatia ("...will be stamped after reaching...", depending on the meaning here of "stamp").  But there's no seafarer's exemption for airport transit visas, only an exemption for those holding a valid visa. But the seafarer doesn't have the valid visa because he'll be getting it at the border.

Comment: @JoErNanO seafarers have special treatment in the visa rules; closing this as a duplicate is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @phoog Can't we add details about seafarers in the linked canonical dupe?

Comment: @JoErNanO we can, but that just makes the canonical question longer, more confusing, and harder to digest for the 99.9% of people who don't need to think about commercial shipping.  There are enough different cases and exceptions and exemptions as it is.  We ought to draw the line somewhere, and this seems to me to be a good place to draw it.

Comment: @phoog There's a dedicated exemption section on the linked canonical. Will it really affect it that much if we add a paragraph saying "seafarers are exempt because phoog said so"? Anyhow this is a weird question [as you say](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72301/seafarer-travelling-to-dubrovnik-from-mumbai-via-munich-do-i-need-a-transit-vis?noredirect=1#comment156438_72301) so I'll retract the close-vote.

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't have the energy right now to read the canonical and form an opinion; I also don't know the answer to this question. They are exempt from having to get a visa before traveling to the border, but there seems to be no special exemption from the ATV, which is a bit weird. Leaving this question separate probably gives the best chance of someone who knows the answer seeing it (not that the chance is all that good, I suppose).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN):

> Nationals of the third countries listed in Annex IV shall be
>   required to hold an airport transit visa when passing through
>   the international transit areas of airports situated on the
>   territory of the Member States.

According to the [German Embassy in India](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/3174898/Daten/3387373/download_datei_transit_visa.pdf), Indian citizens also need to obtain an airport transit visa:

> All Indian citizens in air transit through Germany need to apply for a transit visa at the Consulate
>   General

There are several exemptions listed in the Visa Code, but none of them apply specifically to seafarers:

> (a) holders of a valid uniform visa, national long-stay visa or
>   residence permit issued by a Member State;
>
> (b) third-country nationals holding the valid residence permits
>   listed in Annex V issued by Andorra, Canada, Japan, San
>   Marino or the United States of America guaranteeing the
>   holder’s unconditional readmission;
>
> (c) third-country nationals holding a valid visa for a Member
>   State or for a State party to the Agreement on the European
>   Economic Area of 2 May 1992, Canada, Japan or the United
>   States of America, or when they return from those countries
>   after having used the visa;
>
> (d) family members of citizens of the Union as referred to in
>   Article 1(2)(a);
>
> (e) holders of diplomatic passports;
>
> (f) flight crew members who are nationals of a contracting
>   Party to the Chicago Convention on International Civil
>   Aviation.

Unless you fall under one of the exemptions listed above, you will need to apply for a transit visa.